# Structure within structure and function in C

Tags: c, function, structure

I've been doing the task of reading data and creating particular structures.
In one structure (which contains in itself another structure) eclipse shows "field 'birth' has incomplete type".
I've searched through web, but it looks like there is some specific mistake.
(Here is shortened version of the code)

```
typedef struct{
    int birthday_day;
    int birthday_month;
    int birthday_year;
} birthday;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    struct birthday birth;

}user;

user usser[100];
int i;

for (i=0;i<100;i++){
    fscanf(input, "%s %i %i %i %i", usser[i].id,  
           usser[i].name, usser[i].birth.birthday_day, usser[i].birth.birhday_month,
           usser[i].birth.birthday_year
};
```

Comment: and Sequence of different parameters. and `scanf` clan requires a pointer to the argument. (E.g. `&usser[i].id`)

Comment: BLUEPIXY, thanks. though, I noticed that only after trying to launch the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct _birthday{
    int birthday_day;
    int birthday_month;
    int birthday_year;
} birthday;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    struct _birthday birth;

}user;
```

or

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    birthday birth;

}user;
```

in your example "birthday" is a new type which doesn't need the keyword "struct". That's why you get the error. You can use this type or give a name to the struct and use it with the keyword struct.

Comment: Thanks! it helped!
will vote up this answer as soon as receive enough points

Comment: Avoid names starting with a leading underscore.  It is perfectly safe and sane to use `typedef struct birthday { … } birthday;` because structure tags are in a separate namespace from typedef names.  You could also have `typedef struct { … birthday birth; } user;` or add the tag with `struct user { … birthday birth; } user;`.

Comment: I added the leading underscore to show the difference, but why should I avoid them at all?